How can cryengine projects to be opened using VSCode?
I want to be able to open a cryengine project with vscode. Since vscode does not support opening solutions I am a little stuck.
I have tried using the C# Dev Kit extension, which can open solutions. But it just displayed "not supported" for every project.
I have also tried an extention called "vscode-solution-explorer"  but it just crashed when I tried to expand any Project.
If there is no real solution. Are there better alternatives to Visual Studio?

So far I figured out that I can simply open the project root folder in VSCode.
Thanks to the CMake extension I can see the project outline, which usually would be defined by the solution (which I cannot use).

I am not sure how to build or debug from VSCode yet, but I'll keep this answer updated.
To build the whole thing just open the "Code" folder and use the provided "CMakeList.txt" file. To run it, I set up this "launch.json":
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Launch CryEngine Game",
            "type": "cppvsdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${your cryengine path}/GameLauncher.exe",
            "args": [
                "-project", "${your project path}/Game.cryproject"
            ],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "console": "integratedTerminal"
        }
    ]
}

